# If $A$ and $B$ are linear transformations on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, then are the matrix representations $n\times n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are linear transformations on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, then are the matrix representations $n\times n$ ? In other words, are they square matrices and are they the same dimension? Or could they be $m\times n$  and $p\times r$  for example...

Comment: If $T : V \to W$ is a linear transformation from vector spaces $V$ and $W$ of dimension $n$ and $m$, respectively, then any matrix representing $T$ has size $m \times n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be linear transformations on a vector space, the input has to be from that vector space, so it has to have $n$ columns, where $n$ is the dimension of the space, and the output does too, so it has to have $n$ rows.

Comment: thank you. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not really about linear transformations, but about bases for vector spaces. If $f:V\to W$ is linear, then expressing it by a matrix requires having bases for $V$ and for $W$ (the column$~j$ of your matrix will express the coordinates of $f(b_j)$ in the basis of $W$, where $b_j$ runs through the vectors of the basis of $V$). If the basis of $V$ has $m$ vectors and the basis of $W$ has $n$ vectors, then the size of the matrix will be $n\times m$.

So your question boils down to: does every basis of $V$ have the same number$~n$ of vectors? The answer is yes: it is a theorem that for any vector space$~V$ for which a finite set of spanning vectors exists (that is, a finite dimensional vector space), there exist bases of $V$ and *all* bases have the same number of vectors. This is the foundation for the notion of dimension, as $\dim V$ is defined to be that constant number.

Comment: If the problem says "Let A and B be linear transformations on a finite dimensional vector space V show that dimRange(AB)$\leq$ min{dimRange(A),dimRange(B)}"  do you think both A and B would be nxn or nxm? I think it has to be nxn in order to form AB...

Comment: The problem is sloppily stated since "linear transformation" does not imply that it is from a space to itself (the term "linear operator" does imply that), so it is unspecified where the values of $A$ and $B$ live. But in order to be able to form the composition $AB$, it is necessary that at least $B$ takes its value in the space $V$ itself, and expressed in a basis would be given by a square matrix. For $A$ this is not clear, and not really needed either to get this result.

Comment: Thank you. We have always used that $V\rightarrow V$... but I will clarify with my professor tomorrow.